# Java reverse order of sublist given wrong results

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I am having a problem. I simplified my code to a small demo program. There is 1 class named `Visitor` and it looks like this:

```
public class Visitor implements Comparable<Visitor> {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private static int lastIdGiven = 0;

    public Visitor(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Visitor(String name) {
        this.id = getNewId();
        this.name = name;
    }

    private int getNewId() {
        this.lastIdGiven++;
        return this.lastIdGiven;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Visitor o) {
        return this.id.compareTo(o.id);
    }
}
```

Then I create a `List<Visitor>` and add 20 visitors to it for my example. What I want is to iterate over the list and grab the 5 visitors below the current one, based on Id.
Here is the code for that:

```
public class Main {

    public static final int NUM_OF_VISITORS_IN_LIST = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Visitor> visitorList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Visitor visitor = new Visitor("visitor " + i.toString());
            visitorList.add(visitor);
        }

        visitorList.sort(Visitor::compareTo);

        for(Visitor visitor : visitorList) {

            int visitorSearchId = visitor.getId();
            Visitor searchVisitor = new Visitor(visitorSearchId);

            int endIndex = Collections.binarySearch(visitorList, searchVisitor);
            int startIndex = endIndex - NUM_OF_VISITORS_IN_LIST;

            if (startIndex >= 0) {
                List<Visitor> foundVisitors = visitorList.subList(startIndex, endIndex);

                // REVERSE THE SORTING
                //foundVisitors.sort(Visitor::compareTo);
                //foundVisitors.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
                System.out.println("For visitor-Id: " + visitor.getId() + ", are the following visitors found:");
                for (Visitor foundVisitor : foundVisitors) {
                    System.out.println("\tId: " + foundVisitor.getId());
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is one visitor print:

```
For visitor-Id: 19, are the following visitors found:
    Id: 14
    Id: 15
    Id: 16
    Id: 17
    Id: 18
```

But now I want to reverse sort the 5 foundVisitors. To do that, I had the code commented out, but I had these lines:

```
foundVisitors.sort(Visitor::compareTo);
foundVisitors.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

However, this resulted me in a very weird list, where it grabs old data from the original list:

```
For visitor-Id: 19, are the following visitors found:
    Id: 18
    Id: 4
    Id: 3
    Id: 2
    Id: 1
```

I thought I would get the following output:

```
For visitor-Id: 19, are the following visitors found:
        Id: 18
        Id: 17
        Id: 16
        Id: 15
        Id: 14
```

The code given up here, is my entire project, so y'all can reproduce it if you want :)
What is going wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your issue you just need to do the following, replace:

```
List<Visitor> foundVisitors = visitorList.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
foundVisitors.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

for:

```
  List<Visitor> sublist = visitorList.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
  List<Visitor> foundVisitors = new ArrayList<>(sublist);
  foundVisitors.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

The `subList` method will not return a new `list` but rather a view of the original list. As one can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

> **subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)** Returns a view of the portion of
> this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex,
> exclusive.

Consequently when you did

`foundVisitors.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());`

you were already *messing* up the order of the original list. Hence, there reason why you need to first do

```
 List<Visitor> foundVisitors = new ArrayList<>(sublist);
```

A side note this :

```
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Visitor visitor = new Visitor("visitor " + i.toString());
        visitorList.add(visitor);
    }
```

can be simplified to :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Visitor visitor = new Visitor("visitor " + i);
        visitorList.add(visitor);
    }
```

**Update:**

Unrelated with the main issue of your question, but still an optimization worth mentioning. Suggested by [Hoger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger?tab=topactivity):

> Using an index based loop would eliminate the need to do a binary
> search for the element whose position you already know. Actually, you
> could loop from this index backwards and print the five elements, then
> you would need neither, sub list nor reverse sorting.

So your code can be simplified to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Visitor> visitorList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Visitor visitor = new Visitor("visitor " + i);
        visitorList.add(visitor);
    }
    visitorList.sort(Visitor::compareTo);
    for(int i = NUM_OF_VISITORS_IN_LIST; i < visitorList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("For visitor: " + visitorList.get(i));
        for(int j = i, end = i - NUM_OF_VISITORS_IN_LIST; j > end;) {
            System.out.println(visitorList.get(--j).getId());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very clear explanation of you :)

Answer (score 2):

It's sorting just fine.  I ignored your loop and just did this.

```
 visitorList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Visitor::getId));
 visitorList.forEach(System.out::println);
 visitorList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Visitor::getId).reversed());
 visitorList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

They sort and print as expected.

I recommend you put this in your Visitor class so you can just print the object.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + id;
}
```

And don't be modifying your `sublist`.  Otherwise you will change the contents of the original.  If you do sort he `sublist` it will only sort those items. Then when you print the items of the original list, only the `sublist` part will be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is in the way you use the method subList(), in particular this statement:

`List<Visitor> foundVisitors = visitorList.subList(startIndex, endIndex);`

According to the Java specification for method subList of List:

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

This means that when you apply a "sort" in the sub list "foundVisitors", it will be immediately reflected on the main one "visitorList", and the final result will be a total mess.

To solve this, you have to create a new List from the sub list, for example you can replace your lines with the following ones:

```
   List<Visitor> foundVisitors = new ArrayList<>(visitorList.subList(startIndex, endIndex));

   // REVERSE THE SORTING
   Collections.sort(foundVisitors, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Try this and see how it works.